msbuild restore with explicit buildconfiguration
We have a VS2022 C# .net8 solution with some projects, that have to be compiled using two different version of an nuget package (npgsql). We solved this with defining a special Buildvariable (OLD_NPGSQL) in a special Buildconfiguration. The project files then have a
<Choose>
    <When Condition="$(DefineConstants.Contains('OLD_NPGSQL'))">
        <ItemGroup>
            <PackageReference Include="Npgsql">
                <Version>4.0.17</Version>
            </PackageReference>
        </ItemGroup>
    </When>
    <Otherwise>
        <ItemGroup>
            <PackageReference Include="Npgsql">
                <Version>8.0.4</Version>
            </PackageReference>
        </ItemGroup>
    </Otherwise>
</Choose>

Tag, which switches the version of the package, depending on wether the OLD_NPGSQL Buildvarible is defined or not.
In IDE every Buildkonfig compiles like a charm. In Solutionexplorer, I can see the package version switching, depending on the buildconfiguration.
The problem is the command line build. I read, that I have to call the target restore prior build, so that msbuild can update the package references.
But msbuild /target:Restore seems to ignore the /p:Configuration= switch. It seems to always use the standard buildconfiguration (which is Debug). So after the restore only the build without the buildvariable runs fine. When I use the special buildconfiguration I get build errors because of a wrong version of the npgsql.dll.
When I choose the special buildconfiguration in IDE, then NOT run a commandline restore but only a commandline build with the special buildconfig, it compiles.
So I would like to know: what command does the IDE call, if I switch the buildconfig.
I see somthing like this from the packagemanager in output:
    Restoring NuGet packages...
    Running restore with 12 concurrent jobs.
    Reading project file C:\Users\name\source\repos\abc\def\Views\Views.csproj.
    etc.

(Verbosity is already "diagnostic".)
This ist not the same msbuild /target:Restore does.
Or, maybe I have to switch the standard buildkonfig prior msbuild /target:Restore. But how to do this?

The example code shows that $(DefineConstants) is being used to switch the package version. I assume that $(DefineConstants) is set differently based on the value of $(Configuration). Is your Choose element after $(DefineConstants) is set? If your Choose element appears first then $(DefineConstants) doesn't yet contain 'OLD_NPGSQL'.

@Jonathan Dodds Thank you, but the sequnce of $(DefineConstants) an  is ok

I did a quick test in VS2022 and found both IDE and command line can work fine.Here are my steps, please check:

Set $(DefineConstants) based on the value of $(Configuration).

<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' != 'Debug'">
        <DefineConstants>OLD_NPGSQL</DefineConstants>
</PropertyGroup>


Add Npgsql reference based the Conditon.

<Choose>
    <When Condition="$(DefineConstants.Contains('OLD_NPGSQL'))">
        <ItemGroup>
            <PackageReference Include="Npgsql">
                <Version>4.0.17</Version>
            </PackageReference>
        </ItemGroup>
    </When>
    <Otherwise>
        <ItemGroup>
            <PackageReference Include="Npgsql">
                <Version>8.0.4</Version>
            </PackageReference>
        </ItemGroup>
    </Otherwise>
</Choose>



Restore with buildvariable.( -p:Configuration=Release) It meets the condition to contain OLD_NPGSQL, therefore add the version 4.0.17.

msbuild ConsoleApp2.csproj -t:restore -p:Configuration=Release



Restore without buildvaribale.(-p:Configuration=Debug). It doesn't meet the condition to contain OLD_NPGSQL,therefore add the version 8.0.4.



This seem to work, as long as you call msbuild with a .csproj.
If you call a .sln, the DefineConstants of the csproj are not known in the moment of restore. Since msbuild calls the restore only once, before building the projects. (Only a guess)

I call msbuild with a .sln via the following command msbuild SolutionName.sln -t:restore -p:Configuration=Release  . Looks like it retrieves all the Projects inside the Solution and then goes to restore corresponding version of packages  according to conditions in project file. See the test result :https://i.sstatic.net/xVUfK3ci.png

Ok thank you.
I also made a minimal example and call msbuild with the .sln file.
Everything works, the way you have explained it.
So there must be something wrong in my original solution or projects.

Okay, if you found the root cause, feel free to let me know the result.

I created a new .sln file for the Solution. And now its somewhat more courios:
Two of the projects do the  of the version of the npgsql.dll. The conditions an variable definition are equal. But one switches while Building, the other one doesnt.
I found the reason for this behavior in msbuildoutput with  -verbosity:diagnostic:
Proj1: Primärverweis "Npgsql, Version=4.0.17.0, 
Proj2: Vereinheitlichter Prim„rverweis "Npgsql, Version=8.0.4.0 ... da AutoUnify auf "true" festgelegt ist.
Now I'm searching for the reason, where AutoUnify comes from in Project 2

This doc AutoUnify Property may help.

I'm not shure.
I moved through the log file and found for both projects:
Target "ResolveAssemblyReferences: (TargetId:154)" in file "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets" from project "C:\Users\wolfgang\source\repos\Leitstand\RustyScreen\Data\Data.csproj" (target "ResolveReferences" depends on it): and ResolveAssemblyReferences: (TargetId:184)...Task Parameter:AutoUnify=True (TaskId:152)
So why the first project does Primary reference "Npgsql,
and the second  Unified primary reference "Npgsql,

And why does a IDE-Build everthing well.
(Also the output of IDE and msbuild in cmd look different (both on verbosity:diagnostic)). Does the IDE use another toolchain than msbuild?

last guess: Project 2 depends on Project 1. But both use npgsql directly. So I had a  <PackageReference Include="Npgsql" .. surrounded by the <Choose> in both .csproj files. Project 2 doesnt need the explicit reference since it has one transitive from Project 1. So when I delete this explicite reference in Project 2, the build runs as it should and ResolveReferences uses the right version  for every project. Should this be the solution?

Ok that was a wrong guess. I tried the same Choose with another nuget package. Project 1 switches the version, Project 2 doesnt. I never had a reference to this package in both projects at one time. It remains a mystery

No better ideas right now. Let's wait and see if anyone else has any good suggestions.

I think I got it. My Choose condition works with the Configuration name  <When Condition="$(Configuration.Contains('PGold'))"> . If no other project references the switching project, it works. If another project has a ProjectReference to it it works too, as long, as its Configuration name is the same, like the switching dependet Project. This was not the case in our original solution. Now every project has a Configuration, matching the Choose condition, regardless, if they have a Choose in theyr csproj or not. Really stange, but it works.

Glad to hear you have found a workaround of this issue. If is possible ,you can add your solution as an answer, this will help other users who has the same issue and someone else may come along with an even better solution to your problem. Just a reminder.   ;)

In this case the name of the projects configuration did the trick. I'm not shure, if it is intended, since the IDE works different.
And it doesn't matter, if I do the choose directly by configuration
    <PropertyGroup>
        <Configurations>Debug;Release;Debug_PGold;Release_PGold</Configurations>
    </PropertyGroup>
...    
    <Choose>
        <When Condition="$(Configuration.Contains('PGold'))">
            <ItemGroup>
                <PackageReference Include="Npgsql" Version="4.0.17" />
            </ItemGroup>
        </When>
        <Otherwise>
            <ItemGroup>
                <PackageReference Include="Npgsql" Version="8.0.5" />
            </ItemGroup>
        </Otherwise>
    </Choose>

or indirectly by a build variable
    <PropertyGroup>
        <Configurations>Debug;Release;Debug_PGold;Release_PGold</Configurations>
    </PropertyGroup>
... 
    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release_PGold|AnyCPU'">
        <DefineConstants>$(DefineConstants);NPGSQL_4_0_17</DefineConstants>
        <Optimize>True</Optimize>
    </PropertyGroup>
...
    <Choose>
        <When Condition="$(DefineConstants.Contains('NPGSQL_4_0_17'))">
            <ItemGroup>
                <PackageReference Include="Npgsql" Version="4.0.17" />
            </ItemGroup>
        </When>
        <Otherwise>
            <ItemGroup>
                <PackageReference Include="Npgsql" Version="8.0.5" />
            </ItemGroup>
        </Otherwise>
    </Choose>

Since at least it depends on the configuration name too.
Switching the project-configuration in solution-configuration only for the projects, that use two different versions of the PackageReference is only enough, if no other project depends on it.
If one uses the 'choosing' project in other projects, also these projects need a matching configuration name.
In my case, I had to go up up two steps in the dependency-tree and create configurations with matching names. (But not to the topmost level project, what also depends on the 'choosing' project over three steps down). So to be shure I created configurations for all projects depending on the 'choosing' project.
